# Continuity of the inverse of a function

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f : (S, d_S) → (T, d_T )$ be a bijective continuous function of metric spaces, and $f^{−1}: (T, d_T ) →(S, d_S)$ be the inverse function.
>
> Which of the following statement(s) is/are true?
>
> $a. f^{−1}$ is always a continuous function.
>
> $b. f^{−1}$is continuous if $(S, d_S)$ is compact.
>
> $c. f^{−1}$ is continuous if $(T, d_T )$ is compact.
>
> $d. f^{−1}$ is continuous if $(S, d_S)$ is connected.

My works  :  my answer  will be option b),c) and d)

because  continuous image  of  compact/connected is  compact/connected and  option a)  is false take $f(x) = 1/x$

Is  my answer correct ?

thanks u

Comment: No, what is the inverse of $f(x)=1/x$? It is $f(x)=1/x$ itself. With the same topology on both sides it is a homeomorphism. Note that $f$ is defined on reals without $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f=1/x$ from where to where and which metric to what?

For the first one, consider $f:\Bbb{R}_{dis} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}_u$ by $f(x)=x$, where $\Bbb{R}_{dis}$ denotes $\Bbb{R}$ with discrete metric and $\Bbb{R}_{u}$ denote $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual metric .Then $f$ is a continuous bijection, but $f^{-1}$ is not continuous

For the fourth and third  one, consider $f:[0, 2 \pi) \rightarrow S^1$ by $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$. Then $f$ is a continuous bijection but $f^{-1}$ is not continuous (at $(1,0))$ even though domain in connected and $S^1$ is compact!

The right answer is option b.

**Proof:**  It is enough to show $f$ is open with the assumption $S$ is compact.

So let $V$ be open in $S$ and so $V^c$ is closed in $S$ and hence compact. Thus, $f(V^c)$ is a compact subset of $T$ and so closed in $T$. Since $f$ is a bijection, $$f(V)=[f(V^c)]^c$$ Hence $f(V)$ is open in $T$!

Comment: thanks a lots  @chinnapparaj